# Input string was not in a correct format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application i write the code like this

```
byte[] byt = new byte[Convert.ToSbyte(textbox1.Text)];
```

it is giving the error that input string was not in a correct  format.

Comment: it couldn't be much more specific , now could it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but are you trying to convert the contents of the text box into a byte array? If so, you can do it like this:

```
byte[] byt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textbox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The text in `textbox1` is not a valid numeral for a signed byte.

Does it have spaces? Letters? ...?

Comment: ya it text box contain letter

Comment: @Surya: Then how do you expect it to give you a valid number?

Comment: actually it is encrypting the text what we enter in the textbox

Comment: it is a SHA256 which convert the encrypted form

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? The `new byte[num]` creates an array of 'num' bytes, where 'num' is usually an integer. All bytes in the array are then 0.

It doesn't create a filled array, as I suspect you may be trying to do.

What are the contents of that `textbox1.Text` that gave the error?

Answer (score 0):

what you want in fact is [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/faq/dotnetstrtobytes.html)

```
 // C# to convert a string to a byte array.
 public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
 {
     System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
     return encoding.GetBytes(str);
 }
```